# ClickListner on Dynamically Created TextArea

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamically created textArea in javascript. I made it "readonly" and set the value using string now i want that whenever click on this textArea a function should be call. But i am trying that but all functions not working.Any help will be appreciated:

Here is my code:

```
    textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
                               textarea.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly'); 
                               textarea.setAttribute("cols",35);
                               textarea.setAttribute("rows",5);
                               textarea.setAttribute("style","overflow:hidden;color: white; font-size: 30px;margin-left:10px;position:relative;margin-top:5px;background:transparent;border:thin;outline:none;");
                               textarea.value=all_sel_questions[(question_shuffled_array[i])];
textarea.addEventListener('onClick', clickonTextArea, false); //Here i am trying to enable click listner on this textarea.
```

**And second method to enable onClick listner:**

textarea.onClick= clickonTextArea; **//But this is not calling on click whether its call on loading of the html.**

Comment: sorry It can be done by :

textarea.addEventListener('click', clickonTextArea, false);//replace onClick with click.

Comment: try `addEventListener('click')` not `'onClick'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Changing onClick to click in the eventlistener

```
textarea.addEventListener('click', clickonTextArea, false);
```